# How can I use soundcloud API to search new songs?

Tags: soundcloud

I can not use soundcloud API to search new songs, example https://soundcloud.com/search?q=nonstop-vol14-phia-sau-em. Soundcloud API return only old songs. 
How can I use soundcloud API to search new songs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SoundCloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference) to search for tracks.

Example: http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&q=nonstop%20Phia%20Sau%20Em&filter=public

Results:

> [{"id":471243825,"kind":"track","created_at":"2018/07/13 16:31:52 +0000","last_modified":"2018/07/13 16:31:54 +0000","permalink":"nonstop-phia-sau-em","permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/vi-t-h-219347540/nonstop-phia-sau-em","title":"Nonstop Phía Sau Em","duration":3284369,"sharing":"public","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/NHQyA6PpGFcT_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/471243825/stream","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/471243825","user_id":398075790,"artwork_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000373448307-3e1aeq-large.jpg","comment_count":0,"commentable":true,"description":"Mọi người nghe nếu có gì sai bỏ qua nha hoặc không hay thì mọi người góp ý giúp mình để mình hoàn thiện hơn nhé. cám ơn mọi người đã cố gắng lắng nghe =))","download_count":10,"downloadable":true,"embeddable_by":"all","favoritings_count":0,"genre":"Soundtrack","isrc":null,"label_id":null,"label_name":null,"license":"all-rights-reserved","original_content_size":78817533,"original_format":"mp3","playback_count":0,"purchase_title":null,"purchase_url":null,"release":"","release_day":null,"release_month":null,"release_year":null,"reposts_count":0,"state":"finished","streamable":true,"tag_list":"","track_type":null,"user":{"avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000472674369-d550z9-large.jpg","id":398075790,"kind":"user","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/vi-t-h-219347540","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/398075790","username":"Việt Hà","permalink":"vi-t-h-219347540","last_modified":"2018/07/13 16:34:28 +0000"},"likes_count":15,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/471243825/attachments","bpm":null,"key_signature":"","user_favorite":false,"user_playback_count":null,"video_url":null,"download_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/471243825/download"},{"id":216723926,"kind":"track","created_at":"2015/07/28 14:58:18 +0000","last_modified":"2018/01/05 14:23:20 +0000","permalink":"mp3-phia-sau-em-kay-tran-ft-binz","permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/binz-le/mp3-phia-sau-em-kay-tran-ft-binz","title":"[mp3] Phía Sau Em - Kay Trần ft Binz","duration":224490,"sharing":"public","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/QFSqry1QpiQh_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/216723926/stream","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/216723926","user_id":11577043,"artwork_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000124615926-ck3v4s-large.jpg","comment_count":199,"commentable":true,"description":"Mixed, Mastered : Sino\nImage : Anh Khôi\nLyrics :\nPhía trước em là đoạn đường dài anh ko nơi đấy\nVì giờ này phía sau lưng em anh bước một mình về\n\nDù đã biết mất em nhưng sao lòng anh vẫn nhói đau \nDù chẳng nói ra câu nhưng anh sẽ luôn ở phía sau \nLà người cho em bờ vai sẽ chia câu chuyện \nI will be waitting for you....for you \nLà người cho em vòng tay bên em mỗi khi \nem khóc vì ai \nChắc có lẽ , Chắc có lẽ,  Chắc có lẽ\nVì em đã quên đi những giấc mơ,\nđể anh lại đây cùng những muộn phiền \nRồi cứ thế em bước đi và không cần nghĩ suy\n A đa phải cố quên đi đau thương người hỡi \n\nChorus : \n\nNo No please come back to me\n i will be waiting for you x2 \nXin em hãy một lần nhìn về phía sau,nơi bình minh \nXin em hãy một lần nhìn về phía sau,nơi hoàng hôn\n Chỉ có mỗi riêng anh luôn chờ em\n\nRap\nNỗi buồn này chắc đâu ai hiểu\nPhố dài ta ngược nhau hai chiều\nAnh về lối cũ ta thường qua\nEm về nơi khác bên người ta\nĐường anh về vẫn là gió và mây\nEm đã xa khỏi vòng tay\nGiờ em thêm 1 người mới còn anh thêm 1 bài hát buồn cùng Kay \nAnh muốn gọi gió cho tóc em bay\n\"Gọi nắng trên vai em gầy\"\nNhư là Trịnh Công Sơn anh viết\nNiềm vui kia anh biết\nChôn vùi mãi nơi đây\nEm cứ để con tim này tổn thương cũng được \n em cứ để lòng tin anh dần chết . \nEm cứ để anh  điên khùng vô cảm  vậy\n mang hết yêu thương đi anh không cần đến .\n Em à ! Đợi chờ không phải là hạnh phúc \nanh biết rằng yêu không nhất thiết phải gần nhau\nnhưng anh thấy nổi nhớ lớn dần lên từng phút \ncảm giác quen thuộc như sắp thêm 1 lần đau ... Vì em\n\nĐã quên đi những giấc mơ để anh lại đây\nCùng những muộn phiền\n(lang thang nơi đây anh bước một mình”\nAnh biết quên mau với em điều đó dễ\nNhững tháng ngày dài đôi ta chỉ có thế\nCon tim cố chấp cứ nghĩ rằng có thể\nThấy em nơi cũ nhưng người đâu có về đâu , no\n\nChorus : \n\nNo No please come back to me\n i will be waiting for you x2 \nXin em hãy một lần nhìn về phía sau,nơi bình minh \nXin em hãy một lần nhìn về phía sau,nơi hoàng hôn\n Chỉ có mỗi riêng anh luôn chờ em\n\nAnh vẫn luôn âm thầm phía sau mà\nĐiều đó em ko cần biết đâu\nGo on và tìm them hạnh phúc\nĐễ những hy vọng trong anh mất dần từng phút\nNếu vô tình em tìm về nơi đầu tiên\nGặp anh nơi đó em đừng ngạc nhiên vì\nAnh vẫn luôn ở đó\n\n\n\n\n\n","download_count":0,"downloadable":false,"embeddable_by":"all","favoritings_count":0,"genre":"VietRap","isrc":null,"label_id":null,"label_name":null,"license":"all-rights-reserved","original_content_size":8970048,"original_format":"mp3","playback_count":0,"purchase_title":null,"purchase_url":null,"release":"","release_day":null,"release_month":null,"release_year":null,"reposts_count":1596,"state":"finished","streamable":true,"tag_list":"RnB","track_type":null,"user":{"avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000207099477-q5ydaq-large.jpg","id":11577043,"kind":"user","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/binz-le","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/11577043","username":"Binz Da Poet","permalink":"binz-le","last_modified":"2017/02/28 05:52:01 +0000"},"likes_count":16079,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/216723926/attachments","bpm":null,"key_signature":"","user_favorite":false,"user_playback_count":null,"video_url":null,"download_url":null},{"id":459239736,"kind":"track","created_at":"2018/06/16 16:36:49 +0000","last_modified":"2018/06/16 16:42:10 +0000","permalink":"nonstop-viet-mix-yeu-em-tu-phia-sauth","permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/phi-lyhoang/nonstop-viet-mix-yeu-em-tu-phia-sauth","title":"nonstop viet mix yeu em tu phia sau...(TH)...","duration":2772582,"sharing":"public","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/t8VGQO0klec0_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/459239736/stream","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/459239736","user_id":247179497,"artwork_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000361561242-7ujman-large.jpg","comment_count":0,"commentable":true,"description":"","download_count":0,"downloadable":false,"embeddable_by":"all","favoritings_count":0,"genre":"nhac viet","isrc":null,"label_id":null,"label_name":null,"license":"all-rights-reserved","original_content_size":110890840,"original_format":"mp3","playback_count":0,"purchase_title":null,"purchase_url":null,"release":"","release_day":null,"release_month":null,"release_year":null,"reposts_count":0,"state":"finished","streamable":true,"tag_list":"","track_type":null,"user":{"avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000314128981-ayx9w6-large.jpg","id":247179497,"kind":"user","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/phi-lyhoang","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/247179497","username":"ly hoang phi","permalink":"phi-lyhoang","last_modified":"2017/06/01 09:15:46 +0000"},"likes_count":3,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/459239736/attachments","bpm":null,"key_signature":"","user_favorite":false,"user_playback_count":null,"video_url":null,"download_url":null},{"id":292714388,"kind":"track","created_at":"2016/11/12 17:16:55 +0000","last_modified":"2018/10/30 12:53:03 +0000","permalink":"nonstop-vinahouse-phia-sau-mot-co-gaidj-mario-remix2016","permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/marionguyen6789/nonstop-vinahouse-phia-sau-mot-co-gaidj-mario-remix2016","title":"Nonstop Vinahouse - Phía Sau Một Cô Gái 2016(Dj Mario - Remix)vol.4","duration":3581330,"sharing":"public","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/K8Qs9AyVZojN_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/292714388/stream","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/292714388","user_id":209547623,"artwork_url":null,"comment_count":26,"commentable":true,"description":"Hay anh lùi bước về sau để thấy e gãy lun nhỉ kkk","download_count":0,"downloadable":false,"embeddable_by":"all","favoritings_count":0,"genre":"","isrc":null,"label_id":null,"label_name":null,"license":"all-rights-reserved","original_content_size":631674924,"original_format":"wav","playback_count":0,"purchase_title":null,"purchase_url":null,"release":"","release_day":null,"release_month":null,"release_year":null,"reposts_count":339,"state":"finished","streamable":true,"tag_list":"Vinahouse","track_type":null,"user":{"avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000270205046-6r633c-large.jpg","id":209547623,"kind":"user","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/marionguyen6789","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/209547623","username":"marionguyen6789","permalink":"marionguyen6789","last_modified":"2016/10/08 15:01:58 +0000"},"likes_count":3039,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/292714388/attachments","bpm":null,"key_signature":"","user_favorite":false,"user_playback_count":null,"video_url":null,"download_url":null},{"id":290942684,"kind":"track","created_at":"2016/11/01 10:25:29 +0000","last_modified":"2016/11/01 10:30:55 +0000","permalink":"nonstop-ph-a-sau-m-t-c-g-i","permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/tu-n-punk/nonstop-ph-a-sau-m-t-c-g-i","title":"Nonstop Phía Sau Một Cô Gái Remix - Liên Khúc Nhạc Trẻ Remix Tâm Trạng Buồn Hay Nhất 2017 Vol 3.mp3","duration":4222461,"sharing":"public","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/fxcKMLv6W85Z_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/290942684/stream","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/290942684","user_id":204626028,"artwork_url":null,"comment_count":14,"commentable":true,"description":null,"download_count":0,"downloadable":false,"embeddable_by":"all","favoritings_count":0,"genre":null,"isrc":null,"label_id":null,"label_name":null,"license":"all-rights-reserved","original_content_size":65981393,"original_format":"mp3","playback_count":0,"purchase_title":null,"purchase_url":null,"release":"","release_day":null,"release_month":null,"release_year":null,"reposts_count":236,"state":"finished","streamable":true,"tag_list":"soundcloud:source=android-3rdparty-upload","track_type":"recording","user":{"avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000203854833-lf2oe9-large.jpg","id":204626028,"kind":"user","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/tu-n-punk","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/204626028","username":"Tuấn Punk","permalink":"tu-n-punk","last_modified":"2017/08/15 17:41:03 +0000"},"likes_count":1557,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/290942684/attachments","bpm":null,"key_signature":"","user_favorite":false,"user_playback_count":null,"video_url":null,"download_url":null},{"id":289891094,"kind":"track","created_at":"2016/10/25 13:16:15 +0000","last_modified":"2018/08/03 14:43:26 +0000","permalink":"nonstop-viet-mix-phia-sau-1-co-gai-han-phuc-nhe-an-coi-remix","permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/an-t-6/nonstop-viet-mix-phia-sau-1-co-gai-han-phuc-nhe-an-coi-remix","title":"NonStop - Việt Mix - Phía Sau 1 Cô Gái -  Hạnh Phúc Nhé - An Còi Remix","duration":5066661,"sharing":"public","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/RGUf9mceUuAb_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/289891094/stream","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/289891094","user_id":68422968,"artwork_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000190557658-142wy6-large.jpg","comment_count":25,"commentable":true,"description":"\n\nhttps://theartistunion.com/tracks/2db482'>Download for free on The Artist Union","download_count":100,"downloadable":false,"embeddable_by":"all","favoritings_count":0,"genre":"","isrc":null,"label_id":null,"label_name":null,"license":"all-rights-reserved","original_content_size":202645420,"original_format":"mp3","playback_count":0,"purchase_title":null,"purchase_url":"https://theartistunion.com/tracks/2db482","release":"","release_day":null,"release_month":null,"release_year":null,"reposts_count":143,"state":"finished","streamable":true,"tag_list":"","track_type":null,"user":{"avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000143131428-r8qclu-large.jpg","id":68422968,"kind":"user","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/an-t-6","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/68422968","username":"An Tộ 12","permalink":"an-t-6","last_modified":"2016/10/15 08:09:36 +0000"},"likes_count":1111,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/289891094/attachments","bpm":null,"key_signature":"","user_favorite":false,"user_playback_count":null,"video_url":null,"download_url":null},{"id":469166688,"kind":"track","created_at":"2018/07/09 04:20:25 +0000","last_modified":"2018/07/09 04:20:39 +0000","permalink":"phia-sau-em-kay-tran-thao-pham","permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/user-196915779/phia-sau-em-kay-tran-thao-pham","title":"Phia Sau Em Kay Tran Thao Pham","duration":212525,"sharing":"public","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/rfDBXoK6xtrU_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/469166688/stream","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/469166688","user_id":281332621,"artwork_url":null,"comment_count":0,"commentable":true,"description":"","download_count":0,"downloadable":false,"embeddable_by":"all","favoritings_count":0,"genre":"","isrc":null,"label_id":null,"label_name":null,"license":"all-rights-reserved","original_content_size":5099031,"original_format":"mp3","playback_count":0,"purchase_title":null,"purchase_url":null,"release":"","release_day":null,"release_month":null,"release_year":null,"reposts_count":44,"state":"finished","streamable":true,"tag_list":"","track_type":null,"user":{"avatar_url":"http://a1.sndcdn.com/images/default_avatar_large.png?1541088121","id":281332621,"kind":"user","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/user-196915779","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/281332621","username":"leim","permalink":"user-196915779","last_modified":"2017/01/09 13:22:03 +0000"},"likes_count":617,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/469166688/attachments","bpm":null,"key_signature":"","user_favorite":false,"user_playback_count":null,"video_url":null,"download_url":null},{"id":363001535,"kind":"track","created_at":"2017/11/30 14:08:54 +0000","last_modified":"2018/10/23 08:25:44 +0000","permalink":"phia-sau-em-binz-ft-kay-tran-full-shen-remix-dj-do-nhung","permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/shenproducer/phia-sau-em-binz-ft-kay-tran-full-shen-remix-dj-do-nhung","title":"Phía Sau Em - Binz ft Kay Trần - ( Full ) Shen Remix [Dj Đỗ Nhung]","duration":359765,"sharing":"public","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/7rZr6RAPViYz_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/363001535/stream","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/363001535","user_id":236134051,"artwork_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000263236277-smk702-large.jpg","comment_count":2188,"commentable":true,"description":"Đây mới là ver chính chủ nhé ! . Ver trên mạng là ver nháp . Click Buy Dlw\nhttps://theartistunion.com/tracks/264675","download_count":0,"downloadable":false,"embeddable_by":"all","favoritings_count":0,"genre":"Dance & EDM","isrc":null,"label_id":null,"label_name":null,"license":"all-rights-reserved","original_content_size":14420461,"original_format":"mp3","playback_count":0,"purchase_title":null,"purchase_url":"https://theartistunion.com/tracks/264675","release":"","release_day":null,"release_month":null,"release_year":null,"reposts_count":2312,"state":"finished","streamable":true,"tag_list":"Shen \"Đỗ Nhung\" Vinahouse \"phía sau em\" kaytran Binz Congdongdjonline","track_type":null,"user":{"avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000471282903-itfxkt-large.jpg","id":236134051,"kind":"user","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/shenproducer","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/236134051","username":"Shen","permalink":"shenproducer","last_modified":"2018/08/04 08:51:58 +0000"},"likes_count":3019,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/363001535/attachments","bpm":null,"key_signature":"","user_favorite":false,"user_playback_count":null,"video_url":null,"download_url":null},{"id":261757835,"kind":"track","created_at":"2016/05/01 05:09:04 +0000","last_modified":"2016/05/01 05:20:09 +0000","permalink":"nonstop-mong-kiep-sau-van-la-anh-em-dj-co-vu","permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/trang-mins-299842550/nonstop-mong-kiep-sau-van-la-anh-em-dj-co-vu","title":"Nonstop - Mong kiếp sau vẫn là anh em - DJ CÒ VŨ","duration":3810917,"sharing":"public","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/xIFva0uuY3JY_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/261757835/stream","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/261757835","user_id":223594104,"artwork_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000160658894-233pn7-large.jpg","comment_count":9,"commentable":true,"description":"","download_count":0,"downloadable":false,"embeddable_by":"all","favoritings_count":0,"genre":"Dancehall","isrc":null,"label_id":null,"label_name":null,"license":"all-rights-reserved","original_content_size":152421755,"original_format":"mp3","playback_count":0,"purchase_title":null,"purchase_url":null,"release":"","release_day":null,"release_month":null,"release_year":null,"reposts_count":89,"state":"finished","streamable":true,"tag_list":"","track_type":null,"user":{"avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000221623842-vuhha0-large.jpg","id":223594104,"kind":"user","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/trang-mins-299842550","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/223594104","username":"Trang Min's","permalink":"trang-mins-299842550","last_modified":"2016/05/01 06:15:58 +0000"},"likes_count":843,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/261757835/attachments","bpm":null,"key_signature":"","user_favorite":false,"user_playback_count":null,"video_url":null,"download_url":null}]

Comment: Your request still give no result with link [https://soundcloud.com/ti-n-anh-277338101/sets/chuoi-t-y-nonstop-vol14-phia](https://soundcloud.com/ti-n-anh-277338101/sets/chuoi-t-y-nonstop-vol14-phia)

Comment: modify the search query

Comment: I had tried many case but this query still can not search this song [https://soundcloud.com/ti-n-anh-277338101/sets/chuoi-t-y-nonstop-vol14-phia](https://soundcloud.com/ti-n-anh-277338101/sets/chuoi-t-y-nonstop-vol14-phia)

Comment: That song does not appear to be publically available through the API. http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/634148970.json?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&filter=public